# How to find a word in a text file and then store the next three lines in a variables?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm pretty new to C+ and i need to get this figured out, Currently i have a text file laid out like so;

```
Username1
Password1
AccountNo1
Balance1
Username2
Password2
AccountNo2
Balance2
Etc...
```

I need to be able to search for a username entered by the user and then write the next three lines to their own variables but being new to the language i'm not too sure how to do that.

Thanks in advance,
Jake Wilcox

Comment: did you try something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string line;
  string pass;
  string accno;
  string ball;
  string enteredName;

  cin>>enteredName;

  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");

  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      if (line.compare(enteredName) == 0)
      {
          getline (myfile,line)
          pass = line;
          getline (myfile,line)
          accno = line;
          getline (myfile,line)
          ball = line;
      }
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 
}
```

But this is not safe, if this line is at end of file (file is incorrect)